# Using Execute Statement with CTE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
PREPARE insert_DEL_CRN(bigint, char, char, char) as 
insert into
deleted_crns(id, crn, ror, cpr) values($1, $2, $3, $4) 
ON CONFLICT (crn) 
DO update 
   set id=$1, ror=$3, cpr=$4;
```

Attempting to use the below CTE expression with `EXECUTE insert_DEL_CRN`

```
WITH deleted_record as (
   delete from crns where crn='8000440000'
   RETURNING id,crn,ror,cpr
) 
execute insert_DEL_CRN 
select deleted_record.id, deleted_record.crn, deleted_record.ror,
deleted_record.cpr 
from deleted_record;
```

result in this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXECUTE"
LINE 1: ... where crn='8000440000' RETURNING id,crn,ror,cpr) EXECUTE in...
```

Any specific problem anyone can point out here.

Comment: This isn't possible. You need to repeat the `insert` statement with the common table expression.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Just a thing can upsert work? instead of insert?

Comment: Yes of course it would.

Comment: prepared statements are isolated - you can't use then as functions in SQL statement. either put the whole CTE into the PS or make CTE alias instead of PS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you help me with the same, Attempting to run this fails

```WITH deleted as (delete from crns where crn='8001231409' RETURNING id,crn,ror,cpr)

insert into deleted_crns(id, crn, ror, cpr) on conflict(crn) do update set id=deleted.id, ror=deleted.ror, cpr=deleted.cpr

select deleted.id, deleted.crn, deleted.ror, deleted.cpr from deleted;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine both statements into one. To reference the values of the conflicting row in the `DO UPDATE` part, use the special keyword `excluded`

```
WITH deleted_record as (
   delete from crns 
   where crn='8000440000'
   RETURNING id,crn,ror,cpr
) 
insert into deleted_crns (id, crn, ror, cpr)
select id,crdn,ror,cpr
FROM deleted_records
ON CONFLICT (crn) 
DO update 
   set id = excluded.id, 
       ror = excluded.ror,
       cpr = excluded.cpr;
```